# unable to import module from site-package

Tags: python, tensorflow, module, python-import, importerror

i am importing a module from sitepackages but showing error.
i am successfully able to import a file eg.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import rnn_cell
```

but when i am going to import a module from rnn_cell by

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.rnn_cell import _norm
```

i am getting error

```
ImportError: cannot import name _norm
```

**P.S. the module _norm() is present there in rnn_cell file.**

Comment: Are you sure that `_norm` is present inside `rnn_cell` module?
Please run `dir(rnn_cell)` to see what it contains or check source code of tensorflow inside your site-pacakges install location: `site-packages/tensorflow/contrib/rnn/python/ops/rnn_cell.py`

Comment: this is what i am importing 

from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops import rnn, rnn_cell
linear = rnn_cell._norm

Comment: & the function name is  [ def _norm(self, inp, scope):]  in  rnn_cell.py file

Comment: Because it's not function, but class method of LayerNormBasicLSTMCell.

Comment: @dkato So what should I do to resolve this?

Comment: Because this is not the only class I am not able to import but importing every other class from cnn_rnn.py throwing same error

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure this method call has meaning, but anyway, first instantiate the `LayerNormBasicLSTMCell` class, then call its (internal) method `_norm`.

```
from tensorflow.contrib.rnn.python.ops.rnn_cell import LayerNormBasicLSTMCell

_norm = LayerNormBasicLSTMCell(10)._norm
print(_norm)
```

Again, this method is for internal use, and is not for outside use. So, I don't think this _norm shortcut has meaning.